# How can I force Déjà Dup to make a full backup?

Tags: 11.10, backup, deja-dup

My déjà dup backup seems to be corrupted, at least it tells me on every backup that there's a CRC error and aborts the backup.

Now I think with a full backup I could fix this, but I haven't found a way to do that easily.

So, is there a setting in déjà dup I could use or some simple steps with duplicity (Considering that I want it to respect my déjà dup settings.)?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your question is **no**.  You *can* force it by deleting your backup files entirely and starting fresh, but I have a better suggestion below.

I'm going to guess you are using Ubuntu 11.04 or earlier?  It sounds like you've hit [bug 676767](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/676767), which was (I thought) fixed in Ubuntu 11.10.

The workaround is to run the following:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/deja-dup
```

If this does not fix the problem, please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+filebug).

Comment: I'm using 11.10, but my backup comes from 11.04. I'm trying your workaround right now, but from that bug report it seems that déjà dup should do this automatically now. If the bug persists I'm going to write a bug report like you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Here's the bug report I've filed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/875676

Answer (score 2):

You would not have to delete your old backup files. Just create a new folder to backup your files to. If you backup to a folder without any prior backup files in it, then déjà dup will create a "first backup". Alternatively, you could move your old backup files to a new folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by going directly to Déjà Dup's backend, Duplicity.

Here's how:

```
duplicity full source_directory target_url
```

However, I don't know you get the exact command needed to duplicate all the options you've stored in Déjà Dup (excluded directories, etc).